# Spark Salt joining no performance improvement

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I have DF(country,id1,id2,id3) where country= India has 3 times more data when compared to other countries. So partitioning on the country was resulting in a long-running India partition/Task. To overcome this.

I did salt joining like below.

```
DF=DF.withColumn("salt", when(col("country") === "India", (((rand(1)*10).cast(IntegerType)) % 3)).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

I need to aggregate and find the minimum timestamp on this, for that, I did the below

```
 DF = DF
    .groupBy("salt",id1,id2,id3)
    .agg(min("id3").alias("timestamp"))
    .groupBy(id1,id2,id3)
    .agg(min("id3").alias("timestamp"))
    .withColumn("created", concat(from_unixtime(col("timestamp"), "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"), lit(".000Z")))
```

Once this is done it needs to be joined with the; previous run of the same dataset lets call it DF2 it is the same as DF but from the previous day's run. For that, I need to add the salt back to DF and replicate DF2, for that, I have done as follows

```
DF2(country,id1,id2,id3)
DF2=DF2.withColumn("salt_seed", when(col("country") === "India", (0 until 3 toArray)).otherwise(Array(0)))
DF2=DF2.withColumn("salt", explode(col("salt_seed"))).drop(col("salt_seed"))
DF=DF.withColumn("salt", when(col("country") === "India", (((rand(1)*10).cast(IntegerType)) % 3)).otherwise(lit(0)))
```

Once I have this they have to joined and pick the latest changes for the matching records and add the new records to the final dataset, for this, I have the following.

```
DF=DF.repartition(col("salt"),col("country"))
  DF2=DF2.repartition(col("salt"),col("country"))
  results = DF2
        .join(broadcast(DF), DF2("id1") === DF("id1") && DF("country") === DF2("country") && DF("salt") === DF2("salt"), "full_outer")
        .select(lower(coalesce(col("DF.ID1"), col("DF2.ID1"))) as "data1",
          coalesce(col("DF.ID2"), col("DF2.ID2")) as "data2",
          coalesce(col("DF.country"), col("DF2.country")) as "country")
```

However, the problem is there is no improvement in the performance at all. Even after adding the salt and repartitioning based on country and Salt, it gives 200 partitions that is same as without the salt and partitioning only on the country column. As you could see I'm broadcasting DF to avoid shuffling and adding salt to remove skew but the performance is the same without any of these changes and the number of partitions will always remain the same 200. Am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: any luck with tthis?